# How to Update a column from the results of a SUM from other table column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update, aggregate-functions

What im looking for is to update a column from table 1 using the results from the SUM of a different column in table 2 for example :

#### table 1

```
id             | views | 
--------------------
1          |   0  |  
2          |   0  |
```

#### table 2

```
show_id    | views | 
--------------------
1          |   5   |  
1          |   10  |  
1          |   10  |  
2          |   10  |  
2          |   10  |  
2          |   10  |
```

Now the two tables are connected by id and show_id there the same value; what i want is to add the sum of views from show_id to id where show_id=id

so at the end table 1 should look like these :

```
id         | views | 
--------------------
1          |   25  |  
2          |   30  |
```

I'm using MySQL  5.1.30

Answer (score 1):

Use an `update` with `join`:

```
UPDATE table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON (t1.id = t2.show_id)
SET t1.views = SUM(t2.views)
GROUP BY t1.id;
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: @OMG thanks, it was in my head, must have been a faulty contact in the keyboard cable.